How is the "simplest form" defined in the case of complex trig expressions?
So, I do a lot of complex trig. Some of it I do by hand, and some with WA, but almost uniformly, WA ends up with a different form of the final expression than I do, and I need to do an "equals" test to figure out if mine is the same as what it came up with. This is all fine. What I'm curious about is how WA (or perhaps) mathematicians in general, agree on what is the simplest or canonical form? For example, there is general agreement that you shouldn't have a root in the denominator of a quotient so we regularly rationalize these. Are there similar rules of elegance for complex trig expressions?
Interestingly, I come across this all the time in chemistry. (Mostly what I do is chemistry, not math, the math is in service of the chemistry.) In chemistry there are canonical ways to draw molecules even though there's no technical reason that these should be this way -- any way is technically correct, but some ways are "nicer" or "standard" (or, as above, "canonical"). This is true even for novel molecules -- I know how to draw complex novel molecules in a way that other chemists will prefer to see them.
Is there a standard for complex trig expressions or is it like the molecules: Something experienced mathematicians just know?

You probably should give some examples. You say "complex", but do you mean like $e^{it} = \cos t + i \sin t$ ?

Already in Precalculus, "the" simplest form of any expression is a relative term. Simplest for what purpose? To read off end behaviour of a polynomial, you need to see its leading term. To see its zeros, you need to see it factored. Cannot have both at once, usually.

Does "WA" refer to Wolfram Alpha? In any case, please spell out acronyms in the question, as they decrease the readability of the text.

@JochenGlueck, I'd always thought "WA" was the abbreviation for the state of Washington... :)

@paulgarrett: Wolfram Alpha? State of Washington? Yah! It's the area code for vehicle registration plates in the world-famous German metropolis Waldeck! :)

Side note: for practical purposes, evaluating two trig expressions at 100 random real numbers is usually sufficient to decide whether they're equal.

@JamesS.Cook BTW, sorry about that. I have this permanent mis-wiring in my head, and have for my whole adult life, of using the word "complex" to mean "complicated". I know I shouldn't do that in math contexts, but I can't seem to unplug that wire! :-)

@JochenGlueck WA is the noise I make whenever WA gets a different answer than I do, and I have to type both of them in (well, at least mine) in order to see whether they're the same. (Sometime this sound is written as "Whaaaaaaaaa!" :-)

Indeed, as others are pointing out the answer to this question depends on context. But as a landmark, you can investigate how the Python package Sympy implements trigsimp(), in particular the trigsimp algorithm of Fu. The open source nature of Python allows for a benchmark.
You can also read the paper Automated and readable simplification of trigonometric expressions by Fu et al.  In this article, there is a comparison of the Fu algorithm with whatever is under the hood of Maple, Mathematica, and Maxim.

Fu et al. is a terrific pointer. Thanks!

As the comments suggest, what counts as "simplest" depends strongly on the purpose. Even something as simple as $\sin(\omega t + C)$ versus $\cos(C) \sin(\omega t) + \sin(C) \cos(\omega t)$ is going to depend on how you like to think about the wave equation.
That said, if you just want to compare two equations for equality, may I suggest expanding them into Fourier series? (i.e. the sine-cosine form here.) Those are canonical representations, and since you are expanding combinations of trig functions, you are probably looking at periodic functions. (But things like $\sin(\theta)+\sin(\sqrt{2}\theta)$ would make things a bit more difficult and you'd have to look at Fourier transforms instead.) For periodic functions, the Fourier representation is no more complicated than an infinite sum and you just have to match the coefficients.

Excellent point about the goal guiding the final form!

One hopes for a canonical form for trig expressions and an algorithm to transform any expression into its canonical form, so that if two expressions are equivalent, one can check by seeing if their canonical forms are equivalent. However, due to a result by Caviness ("On Canonical Forms and Simplification", 1970) extending Richardson's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem), checking if two expressions involving rational numbers, $\pi, x, +, -, \cdot, \sin$ and absolute value are equivalent is undecidable. That is, any algorithm for this task is necessarily flawed, ideally because it fails to recognize two equivalent expressions.
Of course this is a purely theoretical result: it doesn't rule out the possibility of really good practical heuristics. It may be there is a heuristic that only fails on impractically large trig expressions.
Others have mentioned that what counts as simple depends on the context: the Caviness paper points out an example due to Fenichel that $\csc^2(x) - \cot(x)\csc(x)$ is simpler if we want to integrate it, but the equivalent $\frac{1}{1+\cos(x)}$ is simpler by most other metrics.

I wish I could nominate multiple correct answers! I guess there's always upvoting. Anyway, thanks for this additional detail.
